# Do I really need a './configure' script for my qt-based project?

Tags: qt, configure

I have already a Makefile generated from a .pro file (via qmake). The only error message that gcc would report would probably be that Qt is not installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qmake` is the "configure" - and it actually allows implementing configure tests, that's how modern Qt is built. The old "configure" script is no more, even for Qt. qmake does it all.

You cannot redistribute a qmake-generated `Makefile`, as it's not portable at all. It is specific to whichever Qt installation you want to build the project with. Recall that a user may have multiple of those.

You can include the following "configure" script with a Qt project:

```
#! /bin/sh
qmake .
```